# Update and delete millions of data in Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a situation where I want to update and delete millions of data and I am using Spring boot cron job. The process includes two things:

1. Fetching records which are older than 6 months and set some status (lets say OPEN or CLOSED).
2. I want to delete all the records which are updated to CLOSED status. The number of records in this case could be in millions and have one-to-many relationship with child entities.

One of the options I could think of is to use deleteAll() together with pagination.

Anyone have some better ideas what could be other possible ways to achieve this?

Comment: You need to delete data from only one table here? I guess there will be multiple related entities to the record that you are deleting and you need to delete them as well.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to have the risks clear in your mind.

- You need to make sure there are no cascade deletes (check the table scheme). if you do, then this adds more complexity and you need to think of the effects
- You need to think of errors that might occur (like some records not being deleted). Do you want to handle those cases somehow? then you need a more custom solution. If you can just rerun the failed cases in a second go, then everything s easier
- You need to think of the live traffic being affected. If you make multiple deletes (and even more if there are cascade deletes) your db will become slower. Which services are using the same db. Will those services be affected? Is there any risk of current users facing issues?
- You need to think of the performance. Can your db and service handle this ok? (maybe running it on a test environment first).

The easiest way, as mentioned before, since you re using spring-data, is to do something like

```
public interface RecordsRepository extends CrudRepository<Record, long> {

    @Transactional
    void deleteByStatus(String status);
}
```

You can use the '@Transactional' annotation if you want it all to happen in one transaction.

If you need to go with a more custom solution, then i guess you go one by one and do the relevant checks, logs, audits etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add something like this in you repository and let Spring generate the appropriate query.

```
long deleteByStatus(Status status);
```

Be careful to also delete the related entities.